# Python encoding (get rid of unnecessary symbols)

Tags: python, encoding

I am scraping a page with **lxml** module.
Everything is scraped correctly with following code:

```
some_element.text_content().encode('utf-8').strip()
```

But one element returns `'+\xc2\xad25550'` string instead of `'+25550'` (as displayed on page). If I delete encode method, `u'+\xad25550'` is returned.
What should be used to get `'+25550'` string?

Comment: If you print it, you'll get what you are after; `print('+\xc2\xad25550')` will give you `+­-25550`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, nope, I get what I wrote as well.

Comment: @lakesare: then you are not printing the unicode string *itself*. If you are writing the UTF-8 string to a console or terminal that is not configured to handle UTF-8, you'll get gibberish (a [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)) or an error instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
some_element.text_content().encode("ascii", "ignore").strip()
```

returned the clean string for me.

Answer (score 0):

`str.strip()` removes whitespace from the start and end *only*. It won't remove whitespace from the middle. Moreover, you have a [U+00AD SOFT HYPHEN](http://codepoints.net/U+00Ad) character in the string, not whitespace.

You can explicitly remove the character with a translation map, passed to the [`unicode.translate()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
toremove = {0xAD: None}
some_element.text_content().translate(toremove).encode('utf8')
```

Each key in `toremove` must be an integer representing a Unicode codepoint (here specified as a hex integer literal), with the value `None` to tell `unicode.translate()` to delete the character altogether.

Demo:

```
>>> sample = u'+\xad25550'
>>> toremove = {0xAD: None}
>>> sample.translate(toremove)
u'+25550'
```

Comment: 'TypeError: expected a character buffer object' somehow rises (though I could repeat it with strings I wrote myself!). (I used strip() to get rid of whitespace before and after the content, just like it's supposed to be used. I just thought it might have some unpredicted by me impact on code)

Comment: @lakesare: note that I specified that you use the `translate()` method on the **unicode** value, so **before** encoding. The error you see is raised because you used the `dict` translation mapping on a `str` string object instead.